# Problem (std::bad_alloc) saving large image (about 36 mb) to postgres DB via QSqlQuery in QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qsqlquery, bad-alloc

I have a problem with QSqlQuery, when trying to save relatively large (~36 mb) image. When I call QSqlQuery::exec(), I get std::bad_alloc exeption. When I work with smaller images, everything is ok. 
Need to be sayed - this code executes in other instance of QThread in order to prevent GUI freezing, all code compiled in MinGW-32 compiler, there are 8 GB RAM on PC. And some times (very rarely) I've got this code running without this exception even with images this size (36 mb)

here is the code:

```
......
QByteArray byte_array_image, byte_array_icon;
QBuffer buffer_image(&byte_array_image), buffer_icon(&byte_array_icon);

buffer_image.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
buffer_icon.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

image->save(&buffer_image, format.toLocal8Bit().data());
icon->save(&buffer_icon, "JPEG");

query.prepare("INSERT INTO pictures (id, id_act, date_time, name, picture, icon) VALUES (:id, :id_act, :date_time, :name, :picture, :icon)");
......
query.bindValue(":picture", byte_array_image);
query.bindValue(":icon", byte_array_icon);
byte_array_image.clear();
byte_array_icon.clear();

save_succeed = query.exec();

if (!save_succeed)
    emit database_failed(QUERY_ERROR_HEADER, QUERY_ERROR_SAVE_IMAGE + query.lastError().text());

emit query_finished();

return save_succeed;
```

As far as I can see, problem can be related with lack of heap space for QApplication to create instance of QString included all bytecode of image. In order to fix that, I ve tried to split this image up to ten parts, but it doesn't help.

Here is ten-parts-splitted query code:

```
............
QByteArray byte_array_image, byte_array_icon;
QBuffer buffer_image(&byte_array_image), buffer_icon(&byte_array_icon);

buffer_image.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
buffer_icon.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

image->save(&buffer_image, format.toLocal8Bit().data());
icon->save(&buffer_icon, "JPEG");

int partlen, parts_count = 0;
save_succeed = false;

while (!save_succeed && ++parts_count < 10)
{
     partlen = byte_array_image.size();
     partlen = byte_array_image.size() / parts_count;

     query.clear();
     query.prepare("INSERT INTO pictures (id, id_act, date_time, name, part_one, parts_count, icon, src, src_act) "
                      "VALUES (:id, :id_act, :date_time, :name, :part_one, :parts_count, :icon, :src, :src_act)");
     ........
     query.bindValue(":part_one", byte_array_image.mid(0, partlen));
     query.bindValue(":parts_count", parts_count);
     query.bindValue(":icon", byte_array_icon);

     try
     {
         save_succeed = query.exec();
     }
     catch (std::bad_alloc &error)
     {
         if (parts_count < 10)
             continue;

         emit database_failed(QUERY_HEAP_ERROR_HEADER, QUERY_HEAP_ERROR_TEXT);

         return false;
     }

 }

 if (save_succeed)
 {
    QStringList part_names = { "part_one", "part_two", "part_three", "part_four", "part_five",
                                   "part_six", "part_seven", "part_eight", "part_nine", "part_ten"};

    for (int current_part = 1; current_part < parts_count; ++current_part)
    {
        query.clear();

        query.prepare("UPDATE pictures SET "+part_names[current_part]+" = :current_part WHERE id = :id AND src = :src");
        query.bindValue(":current_part", current_part == parts_count - 1 ? byte_array_image.mid(current_part*partlen) : byte_array_image.mid(current_part*partlen, partlen));
        ........
        save_succeed = query.exec();
    }
 }

 byte_array_image.clear();
 byte_array_icon.clear();
```

Am I correct with the problem source? Is there anything I can do to fix it? 36 mb for image is not so much.

Comment: *36 mb for image* -- That has to be 36 MB of *contiguous*, free memory, not just 36 MB of free memory.  --   *There are 8 GB RAM on PC* -- That means absolutely nothing if your program is 32-bit.  Only 64-bit programs will gain anything from that memory.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Is there anything I can do to get 36 mb of contiguous free memory? Except for going to 64-bit? And moresoover, I've tried to split this query in ten parts, so this code would demand only ~4mb of free contiguous mem. Why didn't it gave me anything?

Comment: I do not know what `query.exec()` does internally.  Do you?  If not, then you have no control over what gets allocated.  Second, `std::bad_alloc` is also thrown when an invalid (i.e. negative) number is given to allocate.  Also, instead of 10 parts, how about 100 parts?  Or 1,000 parts?  Figure out if this is really related to memory, or just a bug in your code.

Comment: Code that works sometimes but not others hints strongly at undefined behaviour somewhere.  The fact that you mention the use of threading only reinforces that suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to edit your `postgresql.conf` - it may be database memory limit, not your application. There are small default values, something around 20Mb of shared buffers. Use this link as an example https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

2) To check if this is a problem from database or yours, before the `exec`, try to alloc and free large memory bffer - few times larger than requested image. If it's ok and `exec` throws memory exception, then problem is in database or driver, not your application.

3) Also you can step into that `exec` under debugger and watch where is that `bad_alloc` happens

Comment: Yeah, I will try that. Bad thing, sometimes this code manages to save large img to db without `std::bad_alloc` so I am afraid thats not the case.